# Warning when I check the reCaptcha server side

Tags: php, recaptcha

i have a warning when i check the reCAPTCHA on server side.
This is my error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=mysecretkey&response=03AHJ_VuvejqLNxxSFNgqAH5ma83UyRQkowutkQBVlxMrsvTH_IyVhOyLWNYgoOZQGEDu0Dt6wMo2xCkcsFv44tcRAh1ysPdJvqSraNxD9e422YKjdxV0ngz1_8kz0QarboIMxKwCjcuoQnPLZGRFf9w9it_JrT9BXFh3AXFb3NZgH3bQGJUz_46TgGATy4-UdKLHyWZG3_CXoIsJyp8lJmzqd4vQoHrqJ2WZSQTZpQsKoww7D399xQqwbd2I5KjGkQblfvj3dAKRGz-vCQ_TRlGmU4PmSu9azdWSCocDu2suYdWNaazunvvYV0dPtG7TGS9YmxbZuz5b0YdSTJqHSwhLdF3i8B5apS_KI1F3K45rrEO88-HlNfxUYzAAkm6mxLtSjfzp_73UUtn2o7k0dQUpFaCnwQuv47a41fBNetIERmsXl7nmFGnRb_SOzbKcYaBueNlhvBvYa8p3lRtN1wA2Fuact9kvDB78fDAIZ2oPaeIDj-_Qme17PPFmQKsyh6Yd--pDu2rz0oSIEU5lWrXslVsdLwV89az4ImndilWbRvNFKMcYoKDuTiaXXWTPu50H5m9bLuCAIw-A0JuDZt6aowm4rgh3HxNTlkD5xBi3An-T7A-oPzxk4AStRBEfNTkEiUbvLiigXIdzvoJCNqJHq9ZWKgJ6k5I0Gm_O5dblIb7QAuqB-zBPV5lL-hrESF9bzoXFdn-P8-AVL9Pg1vr8V0PfPOyjLg3-A5dSvi9HT7GIBbkvnu-FXdNCO7RXy-aQqqHRmgs7Tl6-6lStdgSvwr1kIWxrXo9Wry6AzWZ1SdYUPjHMYhxhTmtGVImwHOELTVHwjnXchrRPJym8_8aY2BXfPSlZWBnT8WodHn-liEAP1yDEWKsTjotiUfwM

I understand  "invalid-input-secret" because I used "mysecretkey" in the url above.  The problem is "invalid-input-response".
I paste my code below.

```
$secretKey = "mysecretkey";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]."&remoteip=".$ip);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1)
{
    echo "you're a robot";
} else {
    echo "form's control";
}
```

Thank you for all your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your `allow_url_fopen = Off` in your `php.ini` that prevents `file_get_contents` from opening URLs.

You could just use cURL for this, something like this:

```
 $fields = array(
        'secret'    =>  "MySecretKey",
        'response'  =>  $captcha,
        'remoteip'  =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: This code works fine, Thank you.
But I also checked my php.ini file and 'allow_url_fopen' is On.
I don't know what was wrong before.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
$secretKey = "mysecretkey";
$captcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]; //Add This Line
```

And Try :

```
$url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secretkey}&response={$captcha}&remoteip={$ip}";

$options = array(
    'secret'    =>  "MySecretKey",
    'response'  =>  $captcha,
    'remoteip'  =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);
$context = stream_context_create( $options );
$responseKeys=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url, FILE_TEXT, $context ) );
if( $responseKeys->success ){
/* everything is ok */
}
else{ 
/* captcha failed */ 
}
```

Comment: `stream_context_create` requires an array of context options, such as `['method' => 'POST']`  

so your options of `secret`, `response`, `remoteip` are meaningless.